# Forward Apache Server to Proxmox Web Gui

Tags: apache

So, I'm pretty new to apache and I'm having some issues finding a solution to my answer.

I have a domain name abcdefg.com (for example) and I have a public facing Fedora apache webserver on my home network at 192.168.10.10. I then have another machine that is a proxmox VE server at 192.168.10.20.

I know I can forward ports and just type [https://abcdefg.com:8006] to get to my proxmox server, but I want to be able to go to abcdefg.com/proxmox and it then somehow make a call to [https://192.168.10.20:8006] internally (https is required).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't need to be spoonfed, I'm just not sure where to start looking. I've already figured out how to use the "Location" tags but its not working for this, seems to be a bit more involved.

--Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a reverse proxy server, which Apache can do with a few extra mods. This will listen on a specific port (Let's say port 444 in your case) and send requests to whatever IP and port you specify behind the scenes.

See the following link for how to reverse proxy a site: [Simple Apache reverse proxy example](http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/116-simple-apache-reverse-proxy-example)

Simply change the **mywebsite.jamescoyle.net** references to point to your internal proxmox box on port 8006 - eg.

```
ProxyPass https://192.168.10.20:8006/
ProxyPassReverse https://192.168.10.20:8006/
```